# How can I use a Regex to get the value from an attribute from a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

Example: 
If I have a string segment and need to get all values from **width**, only from **img** tags, I don't know how to do it using only one Regex.

By my current knowledge in regex, I would use 3 regexes to do this: First I get all desired HTML tags first (`/\<img(.*?)\/?\>/g`), then the attribute (`/width=\".*?\"/g`), and finally, get the content between quotes (`/\".[0-9]*?\"/g`).

<sub>**EDITED:** Ps.: I'm just asking this for learning purposes in Regex, **I'm not planning to parse HTML documents**. Currently I get this information using Jquery (`$("img").attr('width')`)</sub>

Comment: Please give us sample input and expected output.

Comment: _"I'm just asking this for learning purposes"_ - Well then for learning purposes you should know that trying to use regex to parse whole html documents is not recommended.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: I never planned to parse HTML docs. The whole point of my question was to select only a part of regex to "strip out", but now I figured it out with @vks's answer. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\<img.*?\bwidth=\"(.*?)\".*?\/?\>
```

This will club your regexs together and get you the desired result.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/8

Comment: Worked! Now I got it! The parenthesis is like the part of regex that I want to "strip out"?

Comment: @MarceloAssis yes it will give you the groups you want while the rest of regex matches.you can access it by match.groups or smoething.